# Writing datetime.datetime() column using pandas.to_sql()

Tags: python, datetime, pandas, sqlalchemy, sqldatatypes

I have a single column dataframe `df` which has column `TS` where

```python
In [1]: type(df.TS.values[0])
Out[1]: pandas.tslib.Timestamp
```

I convert the column to type `datetime.datetime()`

```python
In [2]: import datetime
In [3]: df['TS'] = df['TS'].astype(datetime.datetime)
```

I want to write this dataframe to a table in a mssql 2008 database using `pd.to_sql()`. So, I run the following.

```python
In [4]: coltype = {'TS': sqlalchemy.TIMESTAMP}

In [5]: df.to_sql(name='Table', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False, dtype=coltype)
Out[5]: ValueError: df (<class 'sqlalchemy.sql.sqltypes.TIMESTAMP'>) not a string
```

I have also tried not converting the column to `datetime.datetime()` and get same error. I have looked through the `sqlalchemy` documentation on column types but cannot figure out what parameter is supposed to pass. Can someone help me understand what I should be passing to write the column to the db as a datetime object?

Comment: Does the table already exist and, if so, is the `TS` column of String type?

Comment: @JoeCondron Yes the dataframe 'already exists', but if it helps, it is the result object of running a query through `pd.read_sql()`. Also, no the entries in `df.TS` have type `pandas.tslib.Timestamp`, which I then convert to `datetime.datetime`. However, running `df.dtypes` returns `datetime64[ns]`.

Comment: You shouldn't need to specify the dtypes yourself (datetime values are supported). Can you try just `df.to_sql(name='Table', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)`?

Comment: @joris Yes, you are right, I had done that anyway but for some reason thought it would insert them all as TEXT. I should have checked. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

In my case (working with a `PostgreSQL` database) the data type for the timestamp column is `sqlalchemy.DateTime`

```
import sqlalchemy    

dtype = {
    "TS": sqlalchemy.DateTime
}
df.to_sql(name="Table", con=engine, if_exists="append", index=False, dtype=dtype)
```

Answer (score 0):

As [@joris said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33022290/writing-datetime-datetime-column-using-pandas-to-sql#comment53874946_33022290)

> You shouldn't need to specify the dtypes yourself (datetime values are supported).

So, removing `dtype=coltype` should solve your problem

```
df.to_sql(name='Table', con=engine, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

The `dtype` is useful for integers with missing values.

To note:

> while pandas is forced to store the data as floating point, the database supports nullable integers. When fetching the data with Python, we get back integer scalars. [Source](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_sql.html)